# Plotting a graph using fExoticOptions package

Tags: r

I have installed a package in R called `fExoticOptions`

Using a function in that package I have found the values of a `StandardBarrierOption` for values of S (the spot price) ranging from 90 to 110

```
> S = 90:110
> S
 [1]  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110
```

This is what I get .... BUT I am unable to make a graph using

```
plot(Value, S)
```

I understand that the lengths of Value and S are different. Value has a length of 1 while S has a length of 20.

How do I resolve this to make a graph of Value versus S

```
library(fExoticOptions)
Value <- StandardBarrierOption ('cuo', S, 0, 120, 90, 1, 0.01, 0.02, 0.1, title = NULL, description = NULL)


> plot(Value, S)
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
   'x' and 'y' lengths differ

> Value

Title:
 Standard Barrier Option 

Call:
 StandardBarrierOption(TypeFlag = "cuo", S = 90:120, X = 0, H = 120, 
 K = 90, Time = 1, r = 0.01, b = 0.02, sigma = 0.1, title = NULL, 
 description = NULL)

    Parameters:
          Value:
 TypeFlag cuo   
 S1       90    
 S2       91    
 S3       92    
 S4       93    
 S5       94    
 S6       95    
 S7       96    
 S8       97    
 S9       98    
 S10      99    
 S11      100   
 S12      101   
 S13      102   
 S14      103   
 S15      104   
 S16      105   
 S17      106   
 S18      107   
 S19      108   
 S20      109   
 S21      110   
 S22      111   
 S23      112   
 S24      113   
 S25      114   
 S26      115   
 S27      116   
 S28      117   
 S29      118   
 S30      119   
 S31      120   
 X        0     
 H        120   
 K        90    
 Time     1     
 r        0.01  
 b        0.02  
 sigma    0.1  



Option Price:
 90.72108 91.6598 92.57593 93.46411 94.31832 95.13186 95.89745 96.60739 97.25371 97.82838 98.32356 98.73186 99.0466 99.26214 99.37406 99.37948 99.2772 99.06784 98.75399 98.34013 97.83269 97.23984 96.57139 95.83852 95.05354 94.22956 93.38018 92.51917 91.66016 90.8163 90
```

Comment: have a look at `str(Value)`. Do you want `Value@price`

Comment: While `S` is a vector, `Value` is a bundle of many things, including the function call, the price, the title, and others.  You need `@` to extract a specific "sub-object" from the `Value` object.  You probably want this: `plot(S, Value@price, type="l")`

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use a loop or lapply/sapply function. Given each iteration, I would store the price and, finally, plot the options prices versus the spot prices.

```
S_seq <- 80:120
Value_f <- function(S) StandardBarrierOption ('cuo', S, 0, 120, 90, 1, 0.01, 
0.02, 0.1, title = NULL, description = NULL)
Value_seq <- lapply(S_seq,Value_f) 
Value_seq <- sapply(Value_seq, function(x) x@price)
plot(Value_seq~S_seq,pch = 20)
lines(predict(loess(Value_seq~S_seq))~S_seq,col = 2)
```

[image]